# How are enums augmentable?

Tags: enums, metaprogramming, raku

In Raku, HOWs must expose a list of *archetypes* through an `archetypes` method, which is used to determine what broader features of types a type implements, e.g. parametricity or composability. I noticed `Metamodel::EnumHOW` (the HOW used with enums) has the `augmentable` archetype, which is given to types that can be extended after composition with the `augment` keyword when the `MONKEY-TYPING` pragma is enabled.

My first guess at why enums would be augmentable would be to allow enum values to be added, so I tried writing this:

```
use v6;
use MONKEY-TYPING;

enum Foo <foo bar baz>;
augment enum Foo <qux>;
say qux;
```

But this throws:

```
bastille% raku test.raku
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/morfent/test.raku
Redeclaration of symbol 'Foo'.
at /home/morfent/test.raku:5
------> augment enum Foo⏏ <qux>;
```

So they're probably not intended to be augmented in this way.

My next guess was that they're intended to be augmentable with regards to the enum values, not the enum type itself. `augment`, interestingly, doesn't take into account what HOW a type actually has when you tell it what kind of type you're augmenting, so I tried augmenting an enum like you would a class:

```
use v6;
use MONKEY-TYPING;

enum Foo <foo bar baz>;

augment class Foo {
    proto method is-foo(::?CLASS:D: --> Bool:D) {*}
    multi method is-foo(foo: --> True)          { }
    multi method is-foo(::?CLASS:D: --> False)  { }
}

say foo.is-foo;
```

Which works:

```
bastille% raku test.raku
True
```

But this doesn't feel like how you're intended to augment enums to me. This usage of `augment` is rather weird, and there isn't any implication that this should be possible to do from its documentation. How are you intended to augment enums?

## FAQ

- `Foo.is-foo` doesn't appear to have any code? What is it doing?

`is-foo` is rather heavy-handed with how it uses features of signatures and parameters. It depends on the following:

- Constant values may be used like types in signatures. This includes enum values, which are dealt with at compile-time.
- A routine can be made to always return a constant value by making one its signature's return value's type.
- Variables for any given parameter in a signature are optional.
- When a colon is placed after the first parameter like this, that first parameter is the signature's *invocant*. In the case of methods, this allows you to type `self` however you want.
- `::?CLASS` is an alias for the class whose scope a method is declared in. This exists in class and role bodies, so despite `Foo` not really being a class, that is what the symbol is referring to.
- `:D` is a type smiley denoting that a type should only typecheck against its own instances, not type objects that typecheck like it.

Since `foo` is a more specific type than `::?CLASS:D` (an alias for `Foo:D`), when invoking this method on `foo`, the `foo` multi will be selected and `True` will get returned, but in any other case, the `::?CLASS:D` multi will be selected and `False` will be returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you can add almost arbitrary attributes and functions to enums.  So I do think augment in the way you describe could make sense.  For example:

```
use MONKEY-TYPING;

enum Days(Monday => 1, Tuesday => 2, Wednesday => 3, Thursday => 4, Friday => 5, Saturday => 6, Sunday => 7); 

augment class Days {
    proto method is-weekend(::?CLASS:D: --> Bool:D) {*} 
    multi method is-weekend(Saturday: --> True)          { } 
    multi method is-weekend(Sunday: --> True) {}
    multi method is-weekend(::?CLASS:D: --> False)  { } 

    proto method days-til-weekend(::?CLASS:D: --> Int:D) {*}
    # there is probably a better way to express this, but
    # hopefully the concept is clear
    multi method days-til-weekend(Monday: --> 4) {}
    ...
}

say Monday.is-weekend;
say Wednesday.days-til-weekend;
say Saturday.is-weekend;
```